# How to not show on the terminal my program

Tags: bash

I use GROMACS. I think about how can I make my script faster.
This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
number=1
for var1 in {1095000..1100000}
do
    gmx hbond -f luteina_wertykalna_1095_1100.xtc -s sim_prz_lut_d.tpr -n kuba_index_sim_prz_lut_d.ndx -hbn eq3_test_$number.ndx -r 0.4 -contact yes -b $var1 -e $var1 <<EOF
8 45 
EOF
    number=$((number+1))
done
```

My script makes 5000 files and it shows on the screen program GROMACS and wants me to choose two numbers (that is why I use <<EOF 8 45 EOF to make this automatically for every file).
But I heard that showing something on the screen takes time, so how to not showing gromacs program in the terminal?
I try to use '>' but still, I see most part of the program (I do not see the part when I should choose the number

```
#!/bin/bash
number=1
for var1 in {1095000..1100000}
do
    gmx hbond >/dev/null -f luteina_wertykalna_1095_1100.xtc -s sim_prz_lut_d.tpr -n kuba_index_sim_prz_lut_d.ndx -hbn eq3_test_$number.ndx -r 0.4 -contact yes -b $var1 -e $var1 >/dev/null <<EOF
8 45 
EOF
>/dev/null
    number=$((number+1))
done
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect you have output to stderr so you should try using `&>/dev/null` instead of `>/dev/null`

Comment: @vdavid I think you should put that as an answer so that Mark can resolve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminals have 3 file descriptors by default:

0. Standard input, a.k.a. `stdin`
1. Standard output, a.k.a. `stdout`
2. Standard error, a.k.a. `stderr`

When redirecting `>/dev/null` it actually redirects the standard output to `/dev/null`, which is strictly equivalent to `1>/dev/null`

However the program may also output to the standard error, in which case you may want to add `2>/dev/null` to suppress stderr messages:

```
gmx hbond >/dev/null 2>/dev/null -f luteina_wertykalna_1095_1100.xtc -s sim_prz_lut_d.tpr -n kuba_index_sim_prz_lut_d.ndx -hbn eq3_test_$number.ndx -r 0.4 -contact yes -b $var1 -e $var1
```

In Bash you may use `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr at the same time:

```
gmx hbond &>/dev/null -f luteina_wertykalna_1095_1100.xtc -s sim_prz_lut_d.tpr -n kuba_index_sim_prz_lut_d.ndx -hbn eq3_test_$number.ndx -r 0.4 -contact yes -b $var1 -e $var1
```